# Possible image to left of long description

Tags: html, css, meteor

A Meteor client template helper has an array of objects `{image: url, label: description}`.   The url is either a valid url to a image file in the public directory or the string 'non'.
The description can be a short few words or a long few lines of text.

I need to come up with a way to display the image to the left of the label but with the following conditions:

1. in case of no image, the label uses the space where the image should have been.
2. in case of long label and image is NOT present, the place where the image should have been does not create an empty space between this item and the item before it.

My suggestive code below fails on both requirements. Any better way to get this done? Thanks

```
.list-item {
  margin: 1em;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.checks-row li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
li .non {
  display: none;
}
img[src="/non"] {
  display: none;
}
.check-image {
  width: 3.5em;
}
```

```html
<template name="checks">
  <form>
    <div class="list-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing, fast find">
    </div>

    <div class="list-item">
      {{#each values}}
      <ul class="checks-row" data-key={{this.key}}>
        <li class="check-image {{this.image}}">
          <img src="/{{this.image}}">
        </li>
        <li class="check-label">{{this.label}}</li>
      </ul>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Fred, this sounds more like it can be solved using CSS. Can you post screenshots of both conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like twig to me

```
{% if this.image %}
image exist
{% else %}
no image exists
{% endif %}
```

you can use that to set a class if image exist and go from that :)

Comment: I am not sure how to use your answer, please explain where and how. thx

Comment: There shoudl be a way to check if your image exist, and if it exists, you can redesign so the image gets to the left, else not.